# Representation of topological group

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, representation-theory, topological-groups

If $G$ is a topological group (for example a Lie group) and $V$ is a real vector space of finite dimension it's defined the concept of *regular representation* of $G$ over $V$ in the following way:

> $P : G \rightarrow GL(V) $ is a regular representation of $G$ on $V$ if is a representation of $G$ as group (i.e. $P$ is a group homomorphism) such that the induced map $G \times V \rightarrow V$ is continuous.

My question is: Is this equivalent to

> $P$ is a continuous homomorphism of groups.

Note: On $V$ and $GL(V)$ there are the natural topologies.

Comment: Yes, I think so but it seems too general. I believe or I hope that for $\mathbb{R}$ it could be prooved simpler.